# Infinitest 5.1.93 not compatible with Springsource Tool Suite 2.8 (Eclipse Indigo)?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite, java-5, infinitest

In a Spring Roo project the tests fail but only when initiated from Infinitest running in Springsource Tool Suite 2.8.0 (STS). As Infinitest 5.1.93 fails to load the Spring context file all tests fail. When I run the same tests myself inside STS they all go green.

I reconfirmed that nothing else was wrong in this project by importing the project to the previous STS 2.7.x instead. Infinitest run the tests green under STS 2.7.x as expected.

Is Infinitest 5.1.93 currently not compatible with Eclipse Indigo and Springsource Tool Suite?

I currently use jdk1.5.

P.S. I initially wrote "Eclipse Juno" so corrected the question to Indigo. See comments below. D.S.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running STS on Eclipse Juno?  This is not an environment that we test for and I would be surprised if it is working (ie- if you could install all the STS bits into a Juno install).

Comment: Well, I must have misunderstood something with the Eclipse project names. I mentioned Eclipse just because not everyone knows about the STS package. 
I was running STS 2.8.0 which is actually based on Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo).
Anyways, with the STS 2.8.1 release Infinitest 5.1.x works again.

Comment: I now seem to have similar but not identical problem with Infinitest 5.1.102 in that it doesn't run tests every time after changes, like adding a new test method or class. As this seems a different issue I'm making it a different question.

Comment: My initial guess (without knowing much about infinitest, is that the plugin is doing some rewriting of class files that is making it no longer compatible with spring.  This is just a barely educated guess.  Are you able to run infinitest on your project from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that problem not using the classpath: for the resource loading but the file: mechanism:

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "file:src/test/resources/context.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Comment: It is not only about STS by any Spring project in my environment.

Comment: Thanks Manfred. Would you know why this was a problem for Infinitest previously? (It's not an issue any longer with STS 3.4.0, which is based on Eclipse Kepler and Infinitest 5.1.110)

Comment: Excellent. This fixes the classpath issues I was having with Infintest.

Comment: In the newest version of eclipse Mars this issue seems to be solved. Actually the classpath is working now.